# how to flush right in same line?

Tags: spacing

In the following MWE, how can I have Spring 1985-86 flush right but in the same line as ABC with Bolton 808 flush left but in the following line? Would there also be a way using tables or tabular?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\title{\ul{Graduate Course} \\ Econometrics Methods I \\ \small Economics 635}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle 
ABC \begin{flushright}
Spring 1985-86
\end{flushright}

Bolton 808
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `\hfill`. You may also want to add `\noindent` before `ABC` to prevent paragraph indentation.

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\title{\ul{Graduate Course} \\ Econometrics Methods I \\ \small Economics 635}
  \date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle 
\noindent
ABC \hfill Spring 1985-86\\
Bolton 808

Content content content content content content 
content content content content content content 
content content content content content.
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]